# how to check if file has been accessed using python

Tags: python, linux, security, filesystems

I'm trying to do a python script that checks if file and/or directory has been accessed as a honeypot to alert me someone  accessing areas of an Ubuntu server they shouldn't. Unfortunately the code below doesn't seem to work. During testing I was able to cat and copy the file without the timestamp changing (also tried st_mtime and st_ctime with no luck).  Suggestions?

```
    import os
    alert_time = os.stat('temp.txt').st_atime
    print(datetime.fromtimestamp(alert_time))
```

Comment: I recommend using an [inotify](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/inotify/) trigger for that.

Comment: What's the file-system, what  are your mount options?  Not all FS support atime, and for many it can be disabled via mount options.  But what @RichardNeumann ... `inotify` is certainly the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for quick replies. Ext4 is file system. Do either of you have a link to a walkthrough to do what I describe using inotify and python?